# How to change space between all letters?

Tags: spacing, fontspec, microtype, kerning

I want to change the default spacing between all letters in the document to be a little bigger. That is I want to be able to manually choose how far apart all letters should be. Should I change the kerning to do this? If so how do I change the kerning given my two font types listed below?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} %allows fro Play italics
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setmainfont[
AutoFakeSlant=0.3,
BoldFont=Play-Bold.ttf,
ItalicFont=Play-Regular.ttf,
BoldItalicFont=Play-Bold.ttf
]
{Play-Regular.ttf}

\setsansfont[AutoFakeSlant=0.3,
BoldFont=Lato-Bold.ttf,
ItalicFont=Lato-Regular.ttf,
BoldItalicFont=Lato-Bold.ttf
]
{Lato-Regular.ttf}

\titleformat{\section}{\rmfamily}{}{0em}{}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\section{section example}
text text text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please tell us whether you employ LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

Comment: @Mico I use LuaLaTeX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just realized I can use `\addfontfeature`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} %allows fro Play italics
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setmainfont[
AutoFakeSlant=0.3,LetterSpace=20.0,
BoldFont=Play-Bold.ttf,
ItalicFont=Play-Regular.ttf,
BoldItalicFont=Play-Bold.ttf
]
{Play-Regular.ttf}

\setsansfont[AutoFakeSlant=0.3,LetterSpace=10.0,
BoldFont=Lato-Bold.ttf,
ItalicFont=Lato-Regular.ttf,
BoldItalicFont=Lato-Bold.ttf
]
{Lato-Regular.ttf}
\titleformat{\section}{\rmfamily}{}{0em}{}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
    
\section{section example}
text text text
\end{document}
```